# Nlog does not work on linux docker container

Tags: c#, docker, nlog

I have the following nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogFile="../app/internal.log"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" >
  <time type='AccurateUTC' />
  <variable name="filePath" value="../app/logs/${shortdate}.log" />

  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="logconsole"
            layout="${level}|${message}|${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="${filePath}"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${callsite}|${message}|${all-event-properties} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile, logconsole" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

This log works without issues on Windows, but running it on the container does nothing.

There is no **internal.log** either, so, I don't know where to look at.

I attached the Nlog logger to the app as follows:

```
private static void ConfigureLogging(HostBuilderContext host, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
    loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    loggingBuilder.AddNLog(host.Configuration);
}
```

I tried multiple things but without luck so far.

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you configured volume-mapping in `docker-compose.yml` ? Have you tried to use absolute paths instead of relative-paths. Ex. `/app/logs/nlog_internal.log` ?

Comment: Yeah! I tried that too :(

Answer (score 1):

Well,
The issue was inside the Dockerfile order execution:
For some reason that I do not know yet, when I was calling:

> RUN apt-get

> RUN wget

And some other commands after

> FROM base AS final

> WORKDIR /app

> COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

Nlog was not able to find the correct directory.
The solution was to do all the "RUN apk..." plumbing just after the first FROM clause.
I hope it helps somebody else with a similar situation.